# How can I use a bookmarklet to temporarily disable an event handler in my website?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, jquery-events, bookmarklet

I made a simple button clicker website in which every time you click the button, it adds to a counter. here is the url:

https://joeceb.w3spaces.com/button-clicker.html

the code was pretty basic and it looked something like this

```js
/* original code */

let clicks = 0
                
function Click() {
  document.getElementById("btn").innerHTML = `${clicks += 1} clicks`
  if (clicks >= 100) {          // achievement at 100 clicks
      document.getElementById("btn").innerHTML = `${clicks} &#x2605 clicks`
  }
}


/* generates button */

function addButton() {
    document.body.style.textAlign = "center";
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    btn.innerHTML = `0 clicks`;
    var att = document.createAttribute("id");
    att.value = "btn";                           
    btn.setAttributeNode(att);
    btn.style.padding = "12pt";
    btn.addEventListener("click", Click);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
addButton()
```

once you reach **100** clicks you'll get a **star** ★ beside your number. in the original, it would have been unlocked once you had reached **10 000** ★ clicks

the problem was if you clicked the button once and then held down the enter key, it would rapidly and continuously increase, so I used jquery to prevent this from happening.

heres the changed script with enter disabled:

```js
/* i stole this answer from another question */
function loadJQuery() {                   // i'm using jquery ver 3.6 btw
import('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js').then(()=>{
$(document).keydown( function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
})
}
loadJQuery();



/* original code */

    let clicks = 0
                    
    function Click() {
      document.getElementById("btn").innerHTML = `${clicks += 1} clicks`
      if (clicks >= 100) {          // achievement at 100 clicks
          document.getElementById("btn").innerHTML = `${clicks} &#x2605 clicks`
      }
    }

    
    /* generates button */

    function addButton() {
        document.body.style.textAlign = "center";
        var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        btn.innerHTML = `0 clicks`;
        var att = document.createAttribute("id");
        att.value = "btn";                           
        btn.setAttributeNode(att);
        btn.style.padding = "12pt";
        btn.addEventListener("click", Click);
        document.body.appendChild(btn);
    }addButton();
```

now it's a little bit harder to reach **100** clicks.

but my question is how could you use an external script like a *bookmarklet* to bypass it incase i need to test something.

i disabled the enter key for a reason. but if i have to re-enable it, I dont want to edit the scource every time and yould rather have something that i could click to temporarily deactivate it. also i cant use any server-side scripts or the debug console as its disabled by the administrator.

you may need to use the websites original source so here it is

```
<script src="/content/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).keypress( function(event){
  if (event.which == '13') {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
</script>
```

Edit: i used to be able to do this `(() => {my-variable = 9999; myFunction();})();` until i fixed it by moving all the code in the same script element and inside braces{} changing the variable scope

Comment: `$(document).unbind("keypress");` ???

Comment: im not sure. it may have been removed in version 3.6

Comment: So off() instead `$(document).off("keypress");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent `enter` exploits, all you need to do is prevent keydown events from being dispatched to the *button* - and you don't need a huge library like jQuery for something that trivial:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if (e.target.matches('#btn') && e.key === 'Enter') e.preventDefault();
});
```

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if (e.target.matches('#btn') && e.key === 'Enter') e.preventDefault();
});

/* original code */

let clicks = 0

function Click() {
  document.getElementById("btn").innerHTML = `${clicks += 1} clicks`
  if (clicks >= 100) { // achievement at 100 clicks
    document.getElementById("btn").innerHTML = `${clicks} &#x2605 clicks`
  }
}

/* generates button */

function addButton() {
  document.body.style.textAlign = "center";
  var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  btn.innerHTML = `0 clicks`;
  var att = document.createAttribute("id");
  att.value = "btn";
  btn.setAttributeNode(att);
  btn.style.padding = "12pt";
  btn.addEventListener("click", Click);
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
addButton()
```

Using `e.target.matches` checks if the enter is going to the `#btn` - if it is, then the key press won't do anything. If the enter is going to anything else (like a `<textarea>`), it won't be interfered with.

Still, if you wanted to bypass the prevention of enter with a script, all you need to do is `.click()` on the button.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  document.querySelector('#btn').click();
}
```

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if (e.target.matches('#btn')) e.preventDefault();
});

/* original code */

let clicks = 0

function Click() {
  document.getElementById("btn").innerHTML = `${clicks += 1} clicks`
  if (clicks >= 100) { // acheivement at 100 clicks
    document.getElementById("btn").innerHTML = `${clicks} &#x2605 clicks`
  }
}


/* generates button */

function addButton() {
  document.body.style.textAlign = "center";
  var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  btn.innerHTML = `0 clicks`;
  var att = document.createAttribute("id");
  att.value = "btn";
  btn.setAttributeNode(att);
  btn.style.padding = "12pt";
  btn.addEventListener("click", Click);
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
addButton()

// userscript or bookmarklet code:
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  document.querySelector('#btn').click();
}
```

Comment: my only problem with that is that i'm tryig to fix those exploits in the site because i think that it's to cheaty, even as the dev.  though that works here it wont work on the website

Comment: What do you mean, it won't work on the website? The `e.target.matches` method should work - press "Run Code Snippet" to see it successfully preventing enters. All you need to do is change the website code to the code in the snippet, and it should do what you're looking for.

Comment: i wanted the space key to stay active because it doesnt repeatedly click when you hold it like the enter key does. and the button on the website has no id. you can check the website which is the link at the top of the question.

Comment: Check `e.key === 'Enter'` to see if the key is enter, and then you can `preventDefault` if needed. Even if the button doesn't have an ID, you should still be able to select it easily with `querySelector` by looking at where it is on the page, but even if not, since it looks like you're creating it with JavaScript, you can use the reference to the created button instead - just reference `btn` (and make sure it's in scope of the keydown handler)